# exec não funciona - aparentemente executa o mesmo arquivo de chamada

Tags: php, shell

Possuo um script demorado que impede a execução de outros processos enquanto ele não termina.

Como solução, resolvi criar um arquivo que o executa pelo comando exec (**mkt-start.php**). Assim:

```
exec('php -f mkt-exec.php > mkt.log &');
```

O & (e comercial) é para que o arquivo **mkt-exec.php** seja executado em segundo plano, de maneira que o navegador não fica esperando o termino da execução.

Porém o resultado do mkt.log é o proprio **mkt.start.php** e não o **mkt-exec.php**, resultando em um loop infinito de execuções.

Quando executo o comando pelo shell (`php -f mkt-exec.php > mkt.log &`) funciona corretamente.

Alguém sabe dizer o porque desse comportamento?

**Obs**: O resultado é o mesmo se colocado o path completo do arquivo e/ou o path completo do php.

Answer (score 3):

O problema era o `safe_mode` do php, para o `exec` funcionar com o próprio php (php [ file ]) o `safe_mode` não pode estar ativo.

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php

Comment: +1 pela resposta, editei e removi o que era irrelevante e adicionei links, o que acho mais estranho é o safe_mode funcionar, vocês devem estar usando PHP5.3 ou mais antigo ainda, algo extremamente incomum nos dias de hoje, ainda mais que php5.3 não é mais mantido, sendo que estamos no 5.6 e 7.1

Comment: Exatamente. É um cliente cujo servidor é antigo (PHP 5.4) e o safe_mode veio ativo. Estamos acostumados ao 7.0. Mas o cliente pagou pelo sistema e não pelo upgrade (não por falta de oferta da nossa parte), então rsssss

Comment: PHP 5.4 não tem `safe_mode`: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php Veja o primeiro item *Safe mode is no longer supported. Any applications that rely on safe mode may need adjustment, in terms of security.*, você deve ter mais de uma versão do PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar no arquivo mkt-exec.php um cabeçalho assim:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// O resto do código
```

Dar permissão de execução com `chmod +x mkt-exec.php` e rodar direto com o comando `exec(mkt-exec.php > mkt.log &)`

**Obs:** O caminho `/usr/bin/php` deve ser o caminho do executável do PHP, pode rodar o comando `which php` que ele mostra onde está.

Comment: Só uma dica, tanto `#!/usr/bin/php` quanto `chmod +x mkt-exec.php` só seriam necessário se fosse executar o `mkt-exec.php` diretamente, **sem precisar** digitar `php ...`.